# Basic question about accessing an array column

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Sorry if this is a duplicate, tis quite basic.
Ive made an array from a csv with d3 as follows

```
d3.csv('/data/multiculture.csv').then(function (rawData) {
rawData.forEach(function (d) {
areaData[d.lga_code] = d.ppl_who_believe_multiculturalism_makes_life_better_perc;
});
```

this data looks like

```
20110: "59.7"
20260: "40.3"
20570: "45.6"
20660: "51.6"
20740: "43.5"
20830: "33.7"
20910: "58"
```

I need to access only the second column to make a scale

```
colourScale = d3.scaleQuantile().domain(areaData.???).range(['rgba(244,239,67,0.9)', 'rgba(243,205,69,0.9)', 'rgba(243,171,71,0.9)', 'rgba(242,137,73,0.9)', 'rgba(242, 69, 78,0.9)']);
```

but I am not sure how to access it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Object.keys()` you can use `map` to obtains the data in the second column as an array:

```
d3.scaleQuantile().domain(Object.keys(areaData).map(val => areaData[val]))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### file.csv

```
title,value
20110,59.7
20260,40.3
20570,45.6
20660,51.6
20740,43.5
20830,33.7
20910,58
```

```js
d3
    .csv("file.csv")
    .then(function (data) {
        colourScale = d3.scaleQuantile().domain(data.map(o => o.value)).range(['rgba(244,239,67,0.9)', 'rgba(243,205,69,0.9)', 'rgba(243,171,71,0.9)', 'rgba(242,137,73,0.9)', 'rgba(242, 69, 78,0.9)']);
    });
```